# Add new element to existing JSON Object with jq when transforming the JSON

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to transform my JSON to a particular format, during that i have a usecase to add a feild which is in a different level of the JSON to a object.

Source JSON (Simplified)

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "ItemName": "Arun 101",
    "fullflow": "true",
    "name": "arunkumar",
    "code": "12345"
  },
  "systemName": "Super Jack",
  "priority": "Rush",
  "materialFiles": [
    {
      "type": "packaging_metadata"
    }
  ]
}
```

Query:

```
{metadata : .metadata+= {"operation":.materialFiles[0].type}, systemName }
```

Expected Output :

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "ItemName": "Arun 101",
    "fullflow": "true",
    "name": "arunkumar",
    "code": "12345",
    "operation": "packaging_metadata"
  },
  "systemName": "Super Jack",
  "priority": "Rush"
}
```

https://jqplay.org/s/rEldNvbbANe

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses and don't update:

```bash
{metadata: (.metadata + {"operation":.materialFiles[0].type}), systemName, priority}
```

```json
{
  "metadata": {
    "ItemName": "Arun 101",
    "fullflow": "true",
    "name": "arunkumar",
    "code": "12345",
    "operation": "packaging_metadata"
  },
  "systemName": "Super Jack",
  "priority": "Rush"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/x_Izchubxla)

Or just alter `.metadata` and `del`ete `.materialFiles`:

```bash
.metadata+= {"operation":.materialFiles[0].type} | del(.materialFiles)
```

```json
{
  "metadata": {
    "ItemName": "Arun 101",
    "fullflow": "true",
    "name": "arunkumar",
    "code": "12345",
    "operation": "packaging_metadata"
  },
  "systemName": "Super Jack",
  "priority": "Rush"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/sZW2jNakyJF)